# Chinese music theory. How to learn?

Tags: learning, classical-music, erhu

**Introduction:**

I started to practice Erhu(二胡) about half a year ago and I have about 7 years experience in acoustic guitar. I'm from Europe, so traditional Chinese music is quite different in structure compared to the Westerner music. After a little background research, I found that Chinese music (especially many popular erhu compositions) often uses a pentatonic scale, which is not typical for Western music.

**Question:**

Can anyone recommend any starting material to study (Chinese) music theory and history (Quite much starter level). For example lecture materials, pdf presentations or video lecture series?
My goal and motivation for studying is to better understand how traditional Chinese composition is constructed, rhythmic, and maybe one day be able to make arrangements.

Comment: This will probably be closed because this site doesn't normally support questions looking for specific materials.  I strongly suspect that Googling for  "Erhu beginner's tutorials " or similar word salads will get you started.

Comment: Pentatonic scales are used all the time in Western music... especially pop music but, even classical.